# Link to main Vue site from Vuepress

Tags: vue.js, vuepress

I have a vuepress site which lives in my current vuejs app at `/docs`.

I am building the site into the main `/dist` folder and deploying them together.

When I am adding a link to the navbar in the `.vuepress/config.js` file the `base` is always appended or if adding the full URL it creates an external link.

```
module.exports = {
  base: "/docs/",
  dest: "dist/docs",
  themeConfig: {
    nav: [
      { text: 'Home', link: 'https://myapp.com/'},
      { text: 'Guide', link: '/guide/'}
    ],
  }
}
```

I can change the way external links are handled, but this is site wide and I do not want this to apply to all links.

In short:

```
{ text: 'Home', link: '/'} // this is directing to /docs due to base
```

I would like, for this to direct to `myapp.com`